# ST_Intersects returns true for Geographies that don't intersect

Tags: postgresql, postgis

I have two geographies in a postgres database, one represents the `America/Detroit` timezone, the other represents `Etc/GMT+1`.

These clearly do not intersect, however my call to [ST_Intersects](https://postgis.net/docs/ST_Intersects.html) returns true.

why is this? the areas do not share any points with each other.

more information below...

mapped out in pgAdmin

[image]

```sql
WITH detroit AS (SELECT * FROM timezone_boundary WHERE tzid='America/Detroit')
SELECT tb.tzid FROM timezone_boundary tb 
  INNER JOIN detroit d 
  ON ST_Intersects(tb.geo_coords, d.geo_coords) IS TRUE AND tb.tzid='Etc/GMT+1';
-[ RECORD 1 ]---
tzid | Etc/GMT+1
```

my schema...

```sql
                           Table "public.timezone_boundary"
   Column   |            Type             | Collation | Nullable |      Default       
------------+-----------------------------+-----------+----------+--------------------
 id         | uuid                        |           | not null | uuid_generate_v4()
 tzid       | text                        |           | not null | 
 geo_coords | geography                   |           | not null | 
 created_at | timestamp without time zone |           | not null | now()
 updated_at | timestamp without time zone |           | not null | now()
Indexes:
    "timezone_boundary_pkey" PRIMARY KEY, btree (id)
    "timezone_boundary_geo_coords_idx" gist (geo_coords)
    "timezone_boundary_tzid_key" UNIQUE CONSTRAINT, btree (tzid)
```

the envelopes...

```sql
SELECT ST_AsGeoJSON(ST_Envelope(geo_coords::geometry)) as envelope FROM timezone_boundary WHERE tzid='America/Detroit' OR tzid='Etc/GMT+1';
-[ RECORD 1 ]--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
envelope | {"type":"Polygon","coordinates":[[[-90.41862,41.696128],[-90.41862,48.306063],[-82.122806,48.306063],[-82.122806,41.696128],[-90.41862,41.696128]]]}
-[ RECORD 2 ]--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
envelope | {"type":"Polygon","coordinates":[[[-22.5,-72.222222],[-22.5,90],[-7.5,90],[-7.5,-72.222222],[-22.5,-72.222222]]]}
```

postgres version

```sql
-[ RECORD 1 ]-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
version | PostgreSQL 12.7 (Debian 12.7-1.pgdg100+1) on x86_64-pc-linux-gnu, compiled by gcc (Debian 8.3.0-6) 8.3.0, 64-bit
```

postgis version

```sql
-[ RECORD 1 ]--------+----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
postgis_full_version | POSTGIS="3.0.3 6660953" [EXTENSION] PGSQL="120" GEOS="3.7.1-CAPI-1.11.1 27a5e771" PROJ="Rel. 5.2.0, September 15th, 2018" LIBXML="2.9.4" LIBJSON="0.12.1"
```

Comment: Could you also provide the geometries?

Comment: hey @JimJones I added the envelopes, the geometries are quite large.  does that help?

Comment: Are you sure you're getting a positive intersection? check this out: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=9d3f3f319e8b7b783beff1335365c44b

Comment: Can you tell what you get from `SELECT ST_IsValidReason(geo_coords) FROM timezone_boundary`?

Comment: hey @JimJones thanks for you help on this.

I took a look at your db fiddle, one difference I am aware of is that the geographies that I have in my database have holes in them, where as the envelopes don't.  I wonder if that is causing an issue somehow.

did you want me to run ST_IsValidReason on a specific record?

Comment: I just wanted to make sure your large geometry is a valid one, that's why I asked `SELECT ST_IsValidReason(geo_coords) FROM timezone_boundary`.. just to make sure.

Comment: Do you also get `true` with this query? `WITH detroit AS (SELECT * FROM timezone_boundary WHERE tzid='America/Detroit')
  SELECT ST_Intersects(tb.geo_coords, d.geo_coords) 
  FROM timezone_boundary tb, detroit d
WHERE tb.tzid='Etc/GMT+1';`

Comment: it looks like both of the geographies in question, when converted to geometries, are valid.  I don't think I can check a geography's validity



`SELECT ST_IsValidReason(geo_coords::geometry) FROM timezone_boundary where tzid='Etc/GMT+1' or tzid='America/Detroit';
-[ RECORD 1 ]----+---------------
st_isvalidreason | Valid Geometry
-[ RECORD 2 ]----+---------------
st_isvalidreason | Valid Geometry
`

Comment: @JimJones yes that returns true